# error when using NSE (in dplyr) : object 'value' not found

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I'm trying to get familiar with using NSE in my code where warranted. Let's say I have pairs of columns and want to generate a new string variable for each pair indicating whether the values in that pair are the same.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df <- tibble(one.x = c(1,2,3,4),
             one.y = c(2,2,4,3),
             two.x = c(5,6,7,8),
             two.y = c(6,7,7,9),
             # not used but also in df
             extra = c(5,5,5,5))
```

I'm trying to write code that would accomplish the same thing as the following code:

```
df.mod <- df %>%
  # is one.x the same as one.y?
  mutate(one.x_suffix = case_when( 
    one.x == one.y ~ "same",
    TRUE ~ "different")) %>%
  # is two.x the same as two.y?
  mutate(two.x_suffix = case_when(
    two.x == two.y ~ "same",
    TRUE ~ "different"))

df.mod
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   one.x one.y two.x two.y one.x_suffix two.x_suffix
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1    1.    2.    5.    6. different    different   
#> 2    2.    2.    6.    7. same         different   
#> 3    3.    4.    7.    7. different    same        
#> 4    4.    3.    8.    9. different    different
```

In my actual data I have an arbitrary number of such pairs (e.g. `three.x` and `three.y`, . . .) so I want to write a more generalized procedure using `mutate_at`.

My strategy is to pass in the ".x" variables as the `.vars` and then `gsub` the "x" for "y" on one side of the equality test inside the `case_when`, like so:

```
df.mod <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(one.x, two.x),
            funs(suffix = case_when(
              . == !!sym(gsub("x", "y", deparse(substitute(.)))) ~ "same",
              TRUE ~ "different")))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: object 'value' not found.
```

This is when I get an exception. It looks like the `gsub` portion is working fine:

```
df.debug <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(one.x, two.x),
            funs(suffix = gsub("x", "y", deparse(substitute(.)))))
df.debug
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   one.x one.y two.x two.y one.x_suffix two.x_suffix
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1    1.    2.    5.    6. one.y        two.y       
#> 2    2.    2.    6.    7. one.y        two.y       
#> 3    3.    4.    7.    7. one.y        two.y       
#> 4    4.    3.    8.    9. one.y        two.y
```

It's the `!!sym()` operation that's causing the exception here. What have I done wrong?

<sup>Created on 2018-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in `!!sym`, as you can see in the following example:

```
df %>% mutate_at( vars(one.x, two.x),
                  funs(suffix = case_when(
                    . == !!sym("one.y") ~ "same",
                    TRUE ~ "different")))
# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#   one.x one.y two.x two.y one.x_suffix two.x_suffix
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>       
# 1     1     2     5     6 different    different   
# 2     2     2     6     7 same         different   
# 3     3     4     7     7 different    different   
# 4     4     3     8     9 different    different
```

The problem is in trying to unquote `substitute(.)` inside `case_when`:

```
df %>% mutate_at( vars(one.x, two.x),
                  funs(suffix = case_when(
                    . == !!substitute(.) ~ "same",
                    TRUE ~ "different")))
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#   Evaluation error: object 'value' not found.
```

The reason for this is operator precedence. From the help page for `!!`:

> The !! operator unquotes its argument. It gets evaluated immediately in the surrounding context.

In the example above, the context for `!!substitute(.)` is the formula, which is itself inside `case_when`. This leads to the expression getting immediately replaced with `value`, which is defined inside `case_when` and which has no meaning inside your data frame.

You want to keep expressions next to their environment, which is what [quosures](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html#capture-expressions-in-quosures) are for. By replacing `substitute` with `rlang::enquo`, you capture the expression that gave rise to `.` along with its defining environment (your dataframe). To keep things tidy, let's move your `gsub` manipulation into a separate function:

```
x2y <- function(.x)
{
  ## Capture the expression and its environment
  qq <- enquo(.x)

  ## Retrieve the expression and deparse it
  txt <- rlang::get_expr(qq) %>% rlang::expr_deparse()

  ## Replace x with y, as before
  txty <- gsub("x", "y", txt)

  ## Put the new expression back into the quosure
  rlang::set_expr( qq, sym(txty) )
}
```

You can now use the new `x2y` function directly in your code. With quosures, no unquoting is necessary because the expressions already carry their environments with them; you can simply evaluate them using `rlang::eval_tidy`:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(one.x, two.x),
                 funs(suffix = case_when(
                   . == rlang::eval_tidy(x2y(.)) ~ "same",
                   TRUE ~ "different" )))
# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#   one.x one.y two.x two.y one.x_suffix two.x_suffix
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>       
# 1     1     2     5     6 different    different   
# 2     2     2     6     7 same         different   
# 3     3     4     7     7 different    same        
# 4     4     3     8     9 different    different
```

---

**EDIT to address the question in your comment**: Mushing all your code into a single line is almost always A Bad Idea™, and I strongly advise against it. However, since this question is about NSE, I think it's important to understand why simply taking the content of `x2y` and pasting it inside `case_when` leads to problems.

`enquo()`, like `substitute()`, look in the calling environment of the function and replace the argument with the expression that was provided to that function. `substitute()` goes only one environment up (finding `value` inside `case_when` when you unquoted it), while `enquo()` keeps moving up as long as the functions in the calling stack correctly handle [quasiquotation](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html#quasiquotation). (And most dplyr/tidyverse functions do.) So, when you call `enquo(.x)` inside `x2y`, it moves up the expressions provided to each function on the calling stack to eventually find `one.x`.

When you call `enquo()` inside `mutate_at`, it is now on the same level as `one.x`, so it too replaces the argument (`one.x` in this case) with the expression that defined it (the vector `c(1,2,3,4)` in this case). This is not what you want. Rather than moving up levels, you now want to stay on the same level as `one.x`. To do so, use `rlang::quo()` in place of `rlang::enquo()`:

```
library( rlang )   ## To maintain at least a little bit of sanity

df %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(one.x, two.x),
   funs(suffix = case_when(
    . == eval_tidy(set_expr(quo(.), 
                            sym(gsub("x","y", expr_deparse(get_expr(quo(.)))))
                       )
            ) ~ "same",
    TRUE ~ "different" )))
# Now works as expected
```

Comment: Thanks! The explanation is very helpful. I have a lot to work through here. I packaged up the x2y function into a single line just to help me see the structure a bit better. `set_expr(enquo(.x), sym(gsub("x", "y", expr_deparse(get_expr(enquo(.x))))))` works fine as an ugly version of the x2y function, but if I take that same line and replace `.x` with `.` and put that inside `eval_tidy()` (i.e., without creating a separate function) I get an exception (<dbl: 1, 2, 3, 4>' not found). Is creating a named function required here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `map`.  We `split` the dataset into pairs of 'x', 'y' columns with the substring of column names, then loop through the `list` of datasets with `map`, `transmute` to create a new 'suffix' column by comparing the rows of each dataset, bind the `list` of datasets to single dataset and bind with the original dataset (`bind_cols`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    select(matches("\\.x|\\.y")) %>%
    split.default(str_remove(names(.), "\\..*")) %>%
    map( ~ .x %>%
                 transmute(!! paste0(names(.)[1], "_suffix") := 
                      reduce(., ~ c("different", "same")[(.x == .y) + 1]))) %>%
    bind_cols %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  one.x one.y two.x two.y extra one.x_suffix two.x_suffix
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>       
#1     1     2     5     6     5 different    different   
#2     2     2     6     7     5 same         different   
#3     3     4     7     7     5 different    same        
#4     4     3     8     9     5 different    different
```

---

Or another option is to create an expression and then parse it

```
library(rlang)
expr1 <- paste(grep("\\.x", names(df), value = TRUE), 
      grep("\\.y", names(df), value = TRUE), sep="==", collapse=";")
df %>% 
    mutate(!!!rlang::parse_exprs(expr1)) %>%
    rename_at(vars(matches("==")), ~ paste0(str_remove(.x, "\\s.*"), "_suffix"))
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  one.x one.y two.x two.y extra one.x_suffix two.x_suffix
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>        <lgl>       
#1     1     2     5     6     5 FALSE        FALSE       
#2     2     2     6     7     5 TRUE         FALSE       
#3     3     4     7     7     5 FALSE        TRUE        
#4     4     3     8     9     5 FALSE        FALSE
```

NOTE: It can be converted to 'same/different' as in the first solution.  But, it may be better to keep it as logical columns

Comment: Thanks. My actual df contains many additional columns (I added that to the example), so this would need to set the others aside first. Maybe with `nest`?